# Where do I exchange Russian currency outside Russia?

Tags: usa, money, russia, exchange

My family has Russian currency, but I can't find anywhere that will exchange it here. I live in the United States and have looked everywhere. All the places we have checked say they do not want it.

Where should I go?

Comment: The US is a very big place. You might want to be a *teensy* bit more specific.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is, "probably back to Russia".  I would be extremely surprised if you could find any currency exchange or bank in the USA that will accept Russian currency.  The only exception could be in some heavily Russian-speaking areas, for example, Brighton Beach in New York, yet even that is questionable.

Your friend's best bet is to hold on to it until his/her next trip to Russia.  I still have some Russian currency from my last trip to Russia about 3 years ago.